# What does this sentence "there could be a return to near greenhouse conditions for the next generation of counter-terrorism threats" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

What does this sentence "there could be a return to near greenhouse conditions for the next generation of counter-terrorism threats" mean?

> John Raine, who previously worked at a senior level in the British government, paints a pessimistic picture of where things are going: "Given not only the quantum of extremism in Afghanistan, but also the strategic advantage which external players will see in having terrorist capabilities there, **there could be a return to near greenhouse conditions for the next generation of counter-terrorism threats**." ([source](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-56860781))

Answer (score 2):

As a greenhouse creates ideal growing conditions for plants, so *greenhouse conditions* are ideal growing conditions for *threats to counter-terrorism activities*, i.e. terrorism.